# How to block this element with an adblocker

Tags: html, css, filter, adblock

On this twitch site there is an annoying element that I want to remove permanently. On the inspector the element is this:

```
<div class="menu-button hover-background-primary">
```

But try as I might, I can't figure out how to write a filter to remove that element with Ublock.

I read that Ublock and ABP use the same syntax. According to [this](https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet),
`##.menu-button hover-background-primary`
should do want I want. But I can't block anything with this pattern, I tried it putting the names of other classes there and it never does anything. How does this work?

Answer (score 2):

The two classes are separated only in the html - you need to join them together in the rule declaration. And in the html the "." is never shown but when you target classes in either CSS or javascript - each class needs to be prefixed with a "." otherwise the browser will interpret that you are trying to target a html element with that name - irrespective of whether it is correct or even present.

```
##.menu-button.hover-background-primary
```

What this targets is the items that has both the "menu-button class" AND the "hover-background-primary" class

you could even just target the more specific class-

```
##.hover-background-primary
```

Comment: I didn't know how to combine the two class names. I did try putting just one name there and that didn't work. I'll try both things again next time the person goes live on twitch and accept the answer if I have success.

Comment: Sorry but that does not work. If I delete the div in the inspector, the annoying window closes. But if I write your suggestions into the custom filter thing, it doesn't block it. (I saved it and then refreshed the twitch page.)

Comment: I'm getting the impression that twitch did something to make adblockers not work. I can block elements with the pattern you've showed me, but it does not work on twitch. I managed to block a jpg by putting it's address into the filter list. But blocking classes does not seem to do anything.

Comment: I eventually succeeded with what I wanted to do. I never figured out how to block classes on twitch, but the hover-background-primary class was inside an iframe that I was able to block.

Answer (score 1):

Those are multiple classnames.

You need the selector `.first-class-name.second-class-name`, which you can put in filter syntax as desired.